# Verifying empty data fields before submitting PHP emailer form

Tags: php, phpmailer

I’m working with a PHP mailer and gathering the information submitted by the user. Some of the input fields are optional, which means some data fields will be empty. I don’t want to print or submit empty lines within the mailer, so I would like to test whether the string is empty or not. If empty, I want to skip it.

For example, in the sample below, in the table within the first , as the information is gathered, I would like to test  $choice1Field to see if it is empty and, if it is, then skip it, as well as $qty1Field. In other words, skip the entire  section.

I don’t know the proper syntax to code what I’m trying to accomplish.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Bill

```
<?php
$choice1Field = $_POST['choice1'];
$qty1Field = $_POST['qty1'];
$choice2Field = $_POST['choice2'];
$qty2Field = $_POST['qty2'];
$choice3Field = $_POST['choice3'];
$qty3Field = $_POST['qty3'];

$body = <<<EOD
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">

<tr bgcolor="#F6EFBA">
<td width="80%" align="left">$choice1Field</td>
<td>$qty1Field</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E8E8FF">
<td width="80%" align="left">$choice2Field</td>
<td>$qty2Field</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#F6EFBA">
<td width="80%" align="left">$choice3Field</td>
<td>$qty3Field</td>
</tr>

Etc., etc., etc.
</table>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $emailField" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n"; 
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isset() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['choice1']) {
   //do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each field that may be empty, try something like this:

```
if (!empty($choice1Field) && !empty($qty1Field)) {
    $body .= <<< EOD
<tr bgcolor="#F6EFBA">
<td width="80%" align="left">$choice1Field</td>
<td>$qty1Field</td>
</tr>

EOD;
}
```